# Remove middle initial only if there is one in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am needing a formula to remove the middle initial of a name that is in this order.

last, first middle

johnson, david s

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
=LEFT(A1,FIND("}}}",substitute(a1&" "," ","}}}",2))-1)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use formula below to extract text upto second space which would eliminate middle name

```
=IFERROR(LEFT(A1,FIND(" ",A1,FIND(" ",A1)+1)),A1)
```

Comment: yup, it would, its now corrected for error handling